# Login using email with registered account with Facebook

Tags: support

Whenever I log in, I have to click the Facebook button and unfortunately, Facebook was blocked by our Internet provider in the company where I'm working.

How can I login using email and password for my account which is registered using Facebook?

Comment: You can create a username/password login - see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704 and follow the steps there...